# Do Hindus intermarry with other religions?

Tags: scripture, belief, culture, marriage, other-religions

- Are Hindus allowed to marry people of other religions?
- If yes, how should they marry someone belonging to a different
  religion?
- Are the rules different for a man and a woman?

Comment: one can convert to hinduism and marry the other person . related: see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26326/13287 and see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26319/13287 and see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26324/13287 and see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24722/13287 and see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24623/13287

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hinduism/Sanatan Dharam is much older than any other practicing religion that's why there is no literature to inter-marry other religions. This is more like a culture question. Culturally People who termed Hinduism as a religion abstain to marry into other religion due to cultural differences and various other reasons like sometime they need to convert to other religion after marriage so they don't marry because of it. Hinduism doesn't stop or encourage anyone to marry with different religion.

Comment: Nice and perfect answer! The answer that I needed for my own life cycle. I would show this one to someone :P Tomorrow ;-)

Comment: Yes, in Hinduism, there isn't a clear difference between believers/non-believers. Hence no mandate not to mix with non-believers.

Comment: This may be true, but the reason is surely _not_ that it is "much older than any other practicing religion". Even if none of the religions that are around _now_ were around when the Vedas were written, there were definitely other religions around at the time.

Comment: @Seshin I have written Practicing religions and I don't see any practicing religion was around that time!

Comment: I do not know what exactly you mean by "practicing religion". Surely the people living in the areas surrounding the people of the Vedic culture had religions of their own, and surely there was some intermingling between the Vedic peoples and the surrounding peoples.

Comment: @senshin How do you know there were religions that which still exists now ?

Comment: @Gaurav I am not saying that those religions exist now. They almost surely don't. That is besides the point. If they existed _then_, there would have been a possibility of Vedic peoples intermarrying with non-Vedic peoples, and so it would make sense for the Vedas or other contemporary scriptures to discuss the possibility. The fact that they do not means that we must look to a different explanation for _why_ they do not.

Comment: mlechas were the non-vedic people and they were considered inferior and barbaric.

Comment: However, it does instruct that "swadharmo nidhanam sreyaha, paradharmo bhayAvaha"

Comment: Haha. How funny it souds- can we marry other religion.

Comment: We are not Hindu, Muslims, Christian or any other tag we hold on ourselves. God has made no religion bar, categories of human beings, or anything like that. We are all Human beings, the Same MahaKali created us, the Same Allah is nurturing us, and the Same God embraces us the end. It is exhilaratingly laughable seeing people calling themselves Hindu, Muslim, Christian, Jain, Sikh, Buddhist, et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

Hinduism=SanathanaDharma=Ultimate way of life=Happiness for all, living a life following Dharmic way....thus include all human on plant earth....Religion=Sampradaya. ...there are many sampradayas on this prithivi=earth; each started by different acharyas, messengers, prophets.  Sapradayas have rules...Dharma is above sampradayas...that explains all humans are allowed to marry under the Dharma

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange. The answers should generally be supported with sources - texts, scriptures, books, etc - Otherwise, it would be beneficial if the answer is posted as comments.