# Are children born to Hindus abroad caste Hindus?

Tags: caste-system

This is not something ancient scriptures would likely have encountered. Would they have the same ritual status as Hindus who traveled abroad?

Comment: related question here - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3898/what-caste-are-foreigners/3900#3900

Comment: also see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3452/converting-to-hinduism-and-caste/24623#24623