# How to identify caste of a non-Hindu/non-Indian?

Tags: caste-system, manu-smriti, varna

Since four Varnas exists in all ethnicities and all species . How can one identity caste of a person who is not Indian.

In the past many foreigners were assimilated in Kshatriya Varna -like Indo-Greeks, Indo-Schythians.

How can one identify the caste of a person of non-Indian origin ?

Comment: They are casteless as per Hinduism. There's a term called - Mlechcha (disambiguation: Derogatory), for non-Hindu people.

Comment: Whats the basis of the statement - that four varnas exist in non-human species and non-Hindua ? This is incorrect

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3898/4732

Answer (score -1):

According to me caste and varna are two different things. Varna is as per the work and personal attributes whereas caste is by birth. Caste is basically lineage whereas as per bhagvad gita varn is based on gun and karma.
So you may know a person caste from his family line whereas varn by his attributes and work.
further, varn are only four it is mainly division of labour whereas caste are numerous.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).