# What can be my first step in my transformation to Hinduism?

Tags: conversion

Recently discovered this practice and I am ready to devote time and effort for what I believe. I just need guidance

Comment: read "good" translations of Hindu scriptures like Upanishads and Gita so that you can understand what you are getting into.. You should then practice Hinduism and if further need be under the guidance of a "suitable" *guru*.

Comment: Varies according to the sect you wish to identify with. Find your guru and he will guide you. Personal questions are not allowed on this site so your question will probably be closed.

Comment: A first step is to stop eating beef.

Comment: also related: see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26326/13287 and see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26319/13287 and see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26324/13287 and see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24722/13287 and see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24623/13287 and see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26301/13287

Answer (score 4):

I recommend to learn Hinduism in **theory** and **practice**.

- Concerning the theory I recommend taking an online course at an academic institution, e.g., look at http://ced.ochs.org.uk/
  If possible you can also take classes at a university of your city which has a department of indology or Hindu studies.
- Concerning practice I recommend to look for a Hindu community in your neighbourhood and to visit their meetings and religious services.

I assume you will find both ways quite different, at best they will complement each other. But it's not unlikely that they will contradict each other.

Hinduism is a broad culture which encompasses a lot of different teachings and practical ways. There is no accordance which teachings are correct. And no interpretation of the canonical literature is authoritative. The most frequently quoted literature are the Vedas including the Upanishads as well as the Bhagavadgita, the Ramayana and the Puranas.
My personal advice is not to follow too prematurely a specific Guru.

Comment: I cannot stress this more.. 
DO NOT take Hinduism studies in a foreign (non-Indian) university. It's filled with half baked knowledge of Hinduism from people who are 'etic' to the tradition. For a detailed read, https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/30120579-academic-hinduphobia

Comment: @Vineet Menon The debate about Doniger's book is very interesting. Malhotra is one of her most fervent critics. But in order to do justice to her and to her book please watch also her interview  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=how-wI-Gxj4 In any case, I recommend to read at least some chapters of her book.

Comment: I have read enough of Doniger, David White, Pollock and Witzel. I appreciate you giving them the benefit of doubt.

Comment: @Vineet Menon If you dislike Doniger and Witzel, could you name some Indian Indologist from the academic domain? Scholars which you consider fair and competent to lead a discussion with non-Indian scholars. What about Dasgupta, Olivelle, Ganeri? Thank you.

Comment: What does 'academic domain' mean? non-practitioner?

Comment: @Vineet Menon "Academic domain" means department at a university, e.g. department for Hindu studies, Sanskrit etc.,