# How to become a Hindu?

Tags: conversion

Say a non Hindu colleague or an acquaintance, approaches you with a request that he/she wants to become Hindu?  What to do and what to tell them?

The top [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/456/8668) to question [Steps-to-convert-to-hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/455/what-are-the-steps-for-a-person-to-take-if-he-she-wants-to-convert-to-hinduism) tells to act like Hindu. I want to understand what comprises "acting like Hindu"?

Hindu philosophy is vast. There are thousands of rituals and practices. Telling someone to read more about it or act like a Hindu is just going to confuse them.

I am looking for concrete steps or activities to recommend. Something on the lines of:

1. Read Bhagwad Gita (which one?)
2. Do Sandhya vandanam (or any such daily ritual)
3. Chant Gayatri Mantra everyday in the morning.
4. ...

Comment: In case you want to read BG online then you can follow this one: https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg

Comment: ***Hindu philosophy is vast. There are thousands of rituals and practices.:*** Exactly. That's why there is no compulsion of following particular Veda/puran, chant a particular mantra, etc.