# Becoming Hindu UK

Tags: conversion

I would like to convert to Hinduism, I am studying and loads of research online suggests I would be given a new name that I would need to legalise to be fully Hindu. Also a certificate to prove such.

Is this right? Just want to get everything in place.

Thank you

Comment: This is personal advice question which is not allowed on this site. But there is a similar question which already been asked, you may want to have a look: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/455/647

Comment: You should then understand that Hinduism is not a religion, first get everything in place inside yourself with studies and devotion , before showing to others somethng.