# How can a European born converted Hindu become a Brahmana?

Tags: scripture, caste-system, astrology, varna, sects

[Converting to Hinduism and Caste](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3452/22667)

**Very interesting Q&A**

My question is:
Because I am white Hindu, how can I become one day a Brahmana?

Also: in astrology Indian websites, my jyotish kundli states that myself I too belong to a Varna Dharma, [for further private proofs, contact in private me, if you need my birthdate I mean] even if I was born in Europe.
This thing is that evaluable nowadays or  is instead regarded as unimportant at all inside Sanatan Dharma communities?

Dhanyawaad - thank you

Comment: There is indeed a process for that. You can check [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16417/can-a-sudra-become-a-brahmin-in-this-birth) particularly the answer by Tejaswee

Comment: @Rickross dhanyanaabada mitr priye ji, lekin mein think that i need to go to India

Comment: Now I understand why Shiva is my Ishta Deva after having read your post!!!! He wants to save meeee! Om Shivaya Namaha, Om Namah Shivaya!!!! Oh @Rickross tumaro priye!!!! Dhanyabada Ji from anahata region 

Comment: @Rickross help me. A user pro- christianity is downvoting all of my questions

Comment: There is post regarding this downvoting on meta: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/is-down-voting-due-to-personal-bias-only-encouraged