# What is Gotra of a person after converting to Hinduism?

Tags: caste-system, marriage, gotra, conversion, non-hindu

When someone converts to hinduism, how is his Gotra determined? (asking for a friend)

This is important in matters of marriage or puja (Pujaris always ask for your gotra) or Shraadh kriya. Is there a default Gotra one can take or change it later? Taking example of an inter faith marriage and assuming marriage ceremonies are being performed as per Hindu rituals, how would his or her gotra be determined? Please enlighten. Thanks.

Comment: related but does not ans my question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3452/converting-to-hinduism-and-caste

Comment: Here in our place, if Gotra is unknown Kashyap gotra is used (the logic given is Lord Parashurama donated the entire earth to Rishi Kashyap)

Comment: I think I have seen Pujaris use Kashyap gotra if I'm unable to recall mine. Thanks.

Comment: You just say Amuka Gotrotpanna. Means unknown gotra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gothra denotes the DNA that a person has inherited from the lineage. So, it is not possible for a newly converted person to know the Gothra. However, the scriptures suggest that anyone who doesn't know their Gothra should say "Narayana Gothra". That's because all of us belong to the Divine ultimately.

Comment: I have also heard that Students refer their gotra to be that of their guru. I recall in Ramanand Sagar's Ramayan, Shri Ram answers like that when asked about his gotra.

Comment: Reference to scripture would be helpful. Even a screenshot of a  karmakand book if you have would do. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to HSE! Answers posted here must be backed up by authentic sources. Please cite sources.