# Did Sri Chaitanyadev ever convert any Muslim to a Vaishnava?

Tags: gaudiya-vaishnavism, chaitanya

Sri Chaitanyadev appeared at a time when the country was under the Islamic rule.

Did Sri Chaitanyadev ever convert any Muslim to Vaishnava?

Looking for answer citing biography of Chaitanya.

Comment: What are authentic biographies? Can you please tell me how to identify?

Comment: Related [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/414/277) and [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18240/277)

Comment: This is about history and other-religions too ..so pls add those tags as well @Pratimaputra

Comment: If you are not accepting from translated versions, then we might say that your question won't be accepted. Because the question is mainly about Chaitanya Mahaprabhu and not translations. This is an English language site. So, we should only write translations. It is also subjective what is authentic. You should keep an open mind while asking questions and should be ready to receive any answer and not what you only like.  Anyone can answer. Only people who know about the topic will answer obviously. The line in the end is meta commentary and not necessary.

Comment: @Pandya you omitted thevword 'Authentic' by edit, Do you know how many biographies of Sri Chaitanya is there in bengali and Odia, and how many of them are thought authentic? If not, please insert back the word 'Authentic' in the question.Before I read and comment or accept, many may read the answers and I do not like a single person to get wrong or fake information.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is one instance found in Chaitanya Charitamrta where Muslims were converted and they were known as Pathan Vaishnavas.

> CC Madhya 18.207 — In this way Śrī Caitanya Mahāprabhu directly
>   initiated the saintly Muslim by advising him to chant the holy name of
>   Kṛṣṇa. The Muslim’s name was changed to Rāmadāsa. Another Pāṭhāna
>   Muslim present there was named Vijulī Khān.

CC Madhya 18.208 —

> Vijulī Khān was very young, and he was the son of the king. All the other
>   Muslims, or Pāṭhānas, headed by Rāmadāsa, were his servants.

CC Madhya

> 18.209 — Vijulī Khān also fell down at the lotus feet of Śrī Caitanya Mahāprabhu, and the Lord placed His foot on his head.

CC Madhya 18.210

> — After bestowing His mercy upon them in this way, Śrī Caitanya
>   Mahāprabhu left. All those Pāṭhāna Muslims then became mendicants.

CC

> Madhya 18.211 — Later these very Pāṭhānas became celebrated as the
>   Pāṭhāna Vaiṣṇavas. They toured all over the country and chanted the
>   glorious activities of Śrī Caitanya Mahāprabhu

Comment: What do you mean by 'all those'? How many ?

Comment: @Pratimaputra the sloka doesn't say anything. Probably one has to refer previous slokas to get the number.

Comment: okay. take your time and please check and make it a full proof answer.Thanks