# What are some Hindu organizations open to converts

Tags: conversion

I'm a would be converted and would like to ask for suggestions for Hindu organizations with an online presence (and preferably an online community) that are open to converts and enquirers. The question is not just for me but all other English-speaking enquirers / potential converts who do not have any Hindu organizations in their area (or even city, town, county etc.).

Comment: Isckon is one of them that I know of...

Comment: There are also some people who are doing research and following path of Kashmir shaivism which is also a good option to be considered

Comment: Would you mind sharing which country you are in?

Comment: Hi Allan! May I ask what made you seek conversion? Not the specific circumstances but which aspect of Hinduism seems to draw you in. This might help with soliciting better answers.

Comment: You can contact Ramakrishna Order  Swamis at this on line website: www.vedanta.org                  You can ask them your question.

Comment: @Allan I would recommend ISKCON. Why? because they have their centers across world in almost all the countries. They have wide range of literature [online](http://www.vedabase.com/) . & most importantly u need not even convert. you just check out with nearest iskcon center and see if it works out for you. With personal guidance from them it would be easier for you. This is my opinion. :)

Comment: @moonstar2001 I live in Denmark.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan The inclusiveness of Hinduism (acceptance of other paths to the truth/God), reincarnation and moksha eventually for everyone as opposed to only one try (life) and either Paradise or Hell, the philosophy and beauty of puja rituals etc.

Comment: You do not need to convert @AllanB. Hinduism is not a religion in which you have to do rituals to "convert'. You can leave your current religion and be hindu just by thought. Be devoted to Shiva, Devi , Vishnu , Ganesha, or any other God you like. This chosen god is called Ishta Devata. And remember, do not change Ishta Devata again and again. And even after IshtaDevata, all Gods can be worshipped. Remember, all Gods are just one, they have taken different from for different temperament of different devotees.

Answer (score 1):

Where you can legally convert to Hinduism?
Goto any Arya samaj temple. After conversion, you will be provided legally valid certificate.

- http://aryasamajthane.com/conversion.html
- http://www.aryasamajmandir.org/affidavit-conversion.htm
- https://www.wikihow.com/Convert-to-Hinduism

Many Hindu/Vedic sects will convert you, such as [Arya samaj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arya_Samaj) , [Shaiva Siddhanta Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saiva_Siddhanta_Church) , [BAPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochasanwasi_Akshar_Purushottam_Swaminarayan_Sanstha), [ISKCON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Society_for_Krishna_Consciousness) etc.

Easiest and smoothest will be Arya samaj , but you can go for ISKCON too

Comment: also related: see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26326/13287 and see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26319/13287 and see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26324/13287 and see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24722/13287 and see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24623/13287 and see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26301/13287