# Is the reconvering of Hindus through "ghar wapsi" (homecoming) based on scripture?

Tags: conversion

nothing in hinduism in enforced strictly.  large numbers of non-hindus have converted through "common law" and thats that.  I remember a strict elderly Iyengar emit smoke from his ears because a non-veg eating Nayudu chap claimed to be a vaishnavite and sported the namam.  I guess over generations such "Hindus" lost their quotes.

According to Wikipedia: "Ghar Wapsi (Hindi, meaning "Back to Home") is a series of religious conversion activities, facilitated by Indian Hindu organizations Vishva Hindu Parishad (VHP) and Rashtriya Swayamsevak Sangh (RSS), to facilitate conversion of non-Hindus to Hinduism"

Does this have a scriptural basis?

does it make a difference if it is a re-conversion - a hindu who converted to another religion and wants to come back?

Comment: Look through the answer to this question. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/407/is-it-true-that-one-can-not-convert-to-hinduism-from-any-other-religion-or-vice/414#414

Comment: very interesting @YDS - you agreed to remove the dup designation of another of my questions - you haven't done it yet - censoring this question has taken priority.

Comment: No i removed my vote on ur another Q that time itself, can you please check?....And this Q looks dupe to me.. :)

Comment: it is not duplicate now @sv.

Comment: There is a smriti which deals with reconversion -  http://hindudharmaforums.com/showthread.php?10850-Who-is-Maharishi-Deval

Comment: @SK The other question also asks: "Is something of that sort mentioned in the Vedas or any other religious text?" This is same as asking "What is the scriptural basis for...?" - you should explain how your question is not a duplicate of the other before it can be reopened.

Comment: my question is about "ghar wapsi"only - have they found a scriptural way of reclaiming Hindus or is it all by decree "from this day on, I declare you a Hindu"? @sv.

Comment: I have added "many details" about devalasmriti  scripture in my answer at https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26319/13287 . see "argument 3" in my answer . You may check "argument 1" also.

Comment: also related: see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26326/13287 and see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26319/13287 and see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26324/13287 and see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24722/13287 and see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24623/13287 and see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26301/13287