# Can a Brahmana boy marry a Muslim girl?

Tags: scripture, marriage, manu-smriti

Pranam,
I read that a Brahmana boy may marry only a Brahmana(of his race),Kshatriya or a Vaishya girl..
And that a king can marry a woman of any race..(Mahabharata)

1)But is it possible for a Brahmana to marry a Muslim girl according to scriptures..
2)Or can the Woman convert to Sanatan Dharma and marry?( Is conversion recommended in our religion)
Please quote scriptures for reference.
Thank You

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do Hindus intermarry with other religions?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19/do-hindus-intermarry-with-other-religions)

Comment: There are already answers on these type of marriages and also conversion. Scriptures will not say Muslims because that's a new religion. Instead you'll find answers about marrying Shudra/chandala/mleccha/etc.

Comment: *Can?* Yes. *Should?* No. Brahmana can have up to 4 wives - a brahmin woman, a kshatriya woman, a vaishya woman, a shudra woman. Even the last 3 are not praised. But marrying lower than even shudra is definitely not allowed if you want to retain your brahmin caste/varna.

Comment: Thanks everyone